# Touch screen PC keyboard input for shortcuts

Tags: usb, hid

In a nutshell thanks to an illness I have I would like a touchscreen that sends nothing more than keyboard commands straight to my PC like a peripheral.

I have seen tons of Pi remote using SSH to send the commands using the Pi as a HID, but none quite what I am looking for or maybe I am looking at it wrong.

I'm looking to plug about a 15" touchscreen (or multiple 7") into the Pi and on those screen(s) I would like to map a bunch of keyboard shortcuts and even just characters to the screen(s) and when I press them it gives me an instant keyboard input to the PC.

I have a couple of old RPi 2 and a whole load of other Arduino stuff etc. that I never got a chance to get into but I haven't bought a thing for this project because I have no idea where to begin. Could be I am looking in the wrong places.

I was also looking at using Pi Peripheral along with it, but I don't know what the limitations are or like I said, even where to start. I don't even know which device is the best to use or if I should use multiple devices. Using a Pi Zero for the physical buttons seemed like a great idea until I just found out they are currently selling at about 6 times their retail price.

Right now I have a full blown Arduino, an Arduino Due, 2 Uno's and a couple of Pi2, one I know is a B 1.1.

To put things into perspective I setup ModBros sensor panel with a display output about 6 months ago, I've used them as media centres, used them as tiny servers and I remember none of it.

So as basic as you can, please.

Comment: what have you tried? ... this is a Q&A site ... not a brainstorming forum ... please ask a specific, answerable question

Comment: start by exploring `how to emulate a PC keyboard?`